# react native Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

my code works but for some reason, I get this warning:
"Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component."

I think it is something to do with these lines (whan i add them i get the error):

```
  const product = state.data.find((data) => data._id === id);



useEffect(() => {
    if ((product.moistureSensor.tests !== undefined) || (product.lightSensor.tests !== undefined)) {
      setDataState({ 'lightSensor': product.lightSensor.tests[product.lightSensor.tests.length - 1].status, 'muisterSensor': product.moistureSensor.tests[product.moistureSensor.tests.length - 1].status });
      console.log(stateData);
    }
  }, []);
```

there is probably something logical in react that I don't understand.
this is the full code -

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
    import {
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      Switch,
      Button,
      TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, View, ActivityIndicator
    } from 'react-native';
    import { client } from '../../api/SocketConfig'
    import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
    import { Context as ProductDataContext } from '../../context/ProductDetailContext'
    import DynamicProgressCircle from '../../components/DynamicProgressCircle';
    
    const SensorDataShow = ({ id }) => {
      const { state } = useContext(ProductDataContext);
      const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [stateData, setDataState] = useState({ 'lightSensor': null, 'muisterSensor': null });
    
      const listener = (dataServer) => {
        console.log(`the data from server:${dataServer}`);
        if (dataServer.lightSensor !== null)
          setDataState({ 'lightSensor': dataServer.lightSensor, 'muisterSensor': dataServer.muisterSensor });
        setLoading(false)
      }
    
      const changeData = () => { client.on("showData", listener) }
      const emitGetData = () => { client.emit("GetData", id) }
    
      let timer = useRef(null);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (loading === true) {
          console.log('timeout started')
          timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log('i am after timeout');
          }, 35000);
        } return () => clearTimeout(timer.current);
      }, [loading]);
    
      const product = state.data.find((data) => data._id === id);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if ((product.moistureSensor.tests !== undefined) || (product.lightSensor.tests !== undefined)) {
          setDataState({ 'lightSensor': product.lightSensor.tests[product.lightSensor.tests.length - 1].status, 'muisterSensor': product.moistureSensor.tests[product.moistureSensor.tests.length - 1].status });
          console.log(stateData);
        }
      }, []);
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        changeData();
        return () => {
          client.removeAllListeners('showData', listener);
        }
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <>
          {stateData.muisterSensor !== null && (
            <>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 28 }}>Moister sensor data:</Text>
              <DynamicProgressCircle
                changingValues={{
                  Percent: parseInt(
                    stateData.muisterSensor
                  ),
                }}
              />
            </>
          )}
    
          {stateData.lightSensor !== null && (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 28 }}>
              Light sensor data:
              {
    
                stateData.lightSensor
              }
            </Text>
          )}
    
    
          {loading === false ?
            <Button
              title="Get Data"
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => {
                emitGetData(id), setLoading(true)
              }}
            />
            : <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="large" color="red" />}
        </>
      );
    };
    
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#00CC00',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
      buttonON: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#00CC00',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
      buttonOFF: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#DB2828',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
      buttonNotOnline: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#9B9D9A',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
      switch: {
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
    });
    
    export default SensorDataShow;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I appreciate any help I can get !

Comment: I edited the post, I hope I did it correctly.

Comment: it is in react native i am not sure it can run, react native can run as react?

Comment: In this `useEffect` product is a dependency, you need to add `product` to the dependency array, `useEffect(() => {
        if ((product.moistureSensor.tests !== undefined) || (product.lightSensor.tests !== undefined)) {
          setDataState({ 'lightSensor': product.lightSensor.tests[product.lightSensor.tests.length - 1].status, 'muisterSensor': product.moistureSensor.tests[product.moistureSensor.tests.length - 1].status });
          console.log(stateData);
        }
      }, []);`

Comment: @yaronk - Sorry, didn't notice that. Your best bet is to go back to plain code blocks, just make sure you have **all** of the necessary code in the question, clearly laid out. Hope you find the problem!